# How do I extract only the bold text from an HTML document?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I need to extract all the bold snippets in the body of an HTML document. I need to do it on server side using Java (not on the browser)

The text on the page can be bold because of tags e.g. `<b>`, `<h1>`, etc., or because of inline CSS styling `style="font-weight:bold;"`, or because of external CSS styling using CSS clases.

I am using Jsoup, but I can use any other library as well to get this done.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does the page have a defined structure, or can it vary? Please post an example HTML page if possible.

Comment: Why did you add javascript's tag? Java would be more appropriate no?

Comment: If you want to do it on the "server side" you should have tagged the question as "java". Jukka K. Korpela has spent some time providing you with an awesome high-quality solution, while you accepted a flawed and cheap one, editing your question and tags so that it "fits" the solution.

Comment: I am sorry for that Slytael. My bad! Thanks for adding the tag.

Answer (score 2):

A plain JavaScript solution: On sufficiently new browsers, you can use the `getPropertyValue` method to retrieve the computed style of an element. You can traverse the document tree and check all text nodes; text nodes do not have style, so you need to check their parents:

```
function consume(string) {
  console.log(string);
}
function traverse(tree) {
  var i;
  if(tree.nodeType === 3) {
    if(getComputedStyle(tree.parentNode).getPropertyValue('font-weight') === 'bold') {
      consume(tree.textContent);
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < tree.childNodes.length; i++) {
    traverse(tree.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
traverse(document.body);
```

Replace `consume` by your own function that processes the bold texts.

It seems that the computed value of `font-weight` is `bold` even when declared as `700`.

Note that this will only pick up text for which font weight is set specifically to bold (700). Elements with a computed font weight of 600, 800, or 900 will most probably appear in bold (depending on availability of typefaces of course). They could be covered by making an obvious modification to the test.

Comment: Great. Do you have also the solution for the server side in Java?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **getElementsByTagName()**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp

also, can be useful **querySelectorAll**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Good luck, Daniel

Comment: not a very good answer. please see the [FAQ] you must explain what to do not just link to a possible answer

Answer (score 1):

For the tags and inline style (e.g. style directly added to html, not contained in an external css stylesheet), you could go with the css selectors [link](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). (for the inline style, it would be `[style*="font-weight:bold;"]`).

Comment: And what about text made bold via an external style sheet?

Comment: IMO it is not possible with jsoup. Then he had to find another library or write down a css parser. Op didn't specify if he had to deal with external css stylesheet, therefore I gave him a solution specifying what it could do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab the element by tag name, and loop through:

```
elem = document.getElementsByTagName("b");

for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
    console.log(elem[i].innerText)
}
```